# How do I return a list of file names from a directory

Tags: f#

**How do I return a list of file names from a directory?**

The following does not compile:

```
    let directory = new DirectoryInfo(deckFilePath)
    let cards = directory.GetFiles() |> Seq.choose (fun c -> Path.GetFileName(c))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `c` in there is already a `FileInfo` so I think what you want is this:

```
let cards = directory.GetFiles() |> Seq.map (fun c -> c.Name)
```

also note that `Seq.choose` is supposed to work with `option`s

---

I just saw that you are asking for a list so you probably want to add `Seq.toList` at the end too